# Why ESLint doesn't detect a global variable of a later ES release?

Tags: javascript, eslint, ecmascript-5

index.js:

```
var mySet = new Set();
```

Command:

```
npx eslint --no-eslintrc index.js
```

Problem:
**ESLint doesn't detect that `Set` doesn't exist in ES5.**

However, ESLint explains (https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/configuring/language-options#specifying-parser-options):

> By default, ESLint expects ECMAScript 5 syntax.

And for the `env` property, that provides global variables (https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/configuring/language-options#specifying-environments):

> es6 - enable all ECMAScript 6 features except for modules (this automatically sets the ecmaVersion parser option to 6).

> for new ES6 global variables, use { "env": { "es6": true } }

Do you know why ESLint doesn't trigger any error for `new Set()`? The problem remains the same if I use an eslintrc with `env` and `parserOptions` empty, or `"ecmaVersion": 5` for `parserOptions`.

Comment: It says "*ECMAScript 5 **syntax***". That does not include the availability of builtins.

Comment: Yes, but: "for new ES6 global variables, use { "env": { "es6": true } }". And I don't have this.

Comment: What rules did you enable that would complain about usage of the `Set` global?

Comment: I don't have set any rule; I don't have set ` { "env": { "es6": true } }` that provides ES6 global variables (like `Set`); then ESLint should detect that `Set` does not exist. Unless `Set` is not a "global variable" in ESLint terms?

Comment: Does your (non-)configuration make eslint complain about usage of other undeclared variables?

Comment: I came to the same question as you! I'm going to answer to my own post: I found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that, as Bergi said, **ESLint did not complain about undefined variables**.

Example:

```
var s = new Set();
var f = new Foo(); // (Foo does not exist)
```

-> ESLint does not complain.

However, if I add `"extends": "eslint:recommended"` to my eslintrc, then both lines fail, because of https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-undef.

Indeed, if I add:

```
{ "env": { "es6": true } }
```

to my eslintrc, then `var f = new Foo();` fails, but `var s = new Set();` does not.